# How can i change position of value in numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

how can i change position of `green circle` by coordinates(x, y) in numpy array?

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array(
    [
        ['', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛']
    ]
)

x, y = tuple(zip(*np.where(matrix=='')))[0]
yield "\n".join("".join(x for x in i) for i in matrix)
```

Comment: It might be handy to store the indices of that circle. When you move it, replace the original with a square and create a new one in the new space.

Comment: what do you mean by change? you give coordinates and the green circles "goes" in the new position while the old one reverts back to square?

Comment: yeah, i try to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the old position to square and the new to circle:

```
old_pos = (0,0)
new_pos = (1,2)

def change_pos(matrix,old,new):
    matrix[old] = '⬛'
    matrix[new] = ''
change_pos(matrix, old_pos, new_pos)
matrix
```

output:

```
array([['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
       ['⬛', '⬛', '', '⬛'],
       ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
       ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛']], dtype='<U1')
```

##### using a class

If your goal is to make some kind of game, you should use a class for your board:

```
import numpy as np
class Matrix():
    def __init__(self, pos=(0,0), size=(3,3)):
        self.pos = pos
        self.matrix = np.empty(size, dtype='<U1')
        self.matrix[:,:] = '⬛'
        self.matrix[pos] = ''
    
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.matrix.__repr__()
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.matrix.__str__()
    
    def change_pos(self, new):
        self.matrix[self.pos] = '⬛'
        self.matrix[new] = ''
        self.pos = new
```

example:

```
m = Matrix()
print(m)

m.change_pos((2,1))
print(m)
```

Comment: @RAINGM if your goal is to make some kind of game, check the update, you might like it ;)

Comment: its even better, thx

Answer (score 0):

```html
import numpy as np
matrix = np.array(
    [
        ['', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛']
    ]
)
def change_green(x, y):
    x1, y1 = tuple(zip(*np.where(matrix=='')))[0]
    matrix[x1][y1] = '⬛'
    matrix[x][y] = ''
change_green(1, 1)
print(matrix)
```

result:

```html
[
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛'],
        ['⬛', '⬛', '⬛', '⬛']
    ]
```